# Use property value in spring initialisation

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to change the session timeout in spring via Java Config (no web.xml).

It looks quite simple if you don't mind hard coding the timeout, however this isn't desired. Is there a way to use the @Value annotation during initialisation?

E.g.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/example/demo.properties")
    public class Initialiser implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    /** Session timeout in seconds. */
    @Value(value = "${session-timeout}")
    private int sessionTimeout;

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext container) {
        container.addListener(new SessionListener(sessionTimeout));
    }
}
```

The field at runtime is 0 as it appears that you can't inject values during startUp. Is there anyway round this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd put it in system properties and do @Value(value="#{systemProperties['session-timeout']}")

Comment: @wyborn Is this issue got resolved? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/example/demo.properties")
public class Initialiser implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext container) {
        container.addListener(new SessionListener(env.getRequiredProperty("session-timeout")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gave me a "Failed to start component" error.

Comment: What is the root error? Can you post the stack trace?